# how to select user from auth_user django python for given username and hashed password

Tags: python, mysql, django, api, hash

i am creating a python api that will return data from mysql database if the email and password are found in the database but the password is hashed, is their any way that i could hash the password entered from the api to compare it to the mysql password.

i am using django.contrib.auth for creating new users that automatically created the table auth_user in the database containing the hashed password.

i know one solution is to store the unencrypted password in another table but can it be done without creating another password field?

i searched a lot and i couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using django-rest-framework. It can handle all the authentication (and more) for you out of the box.

Comment: @m_____z rest framework is extended by django itself. Django provides all the authentication facility already, no need of rest framework

Comment: What I meant is that there's no need to manually compare the passwords (even by using the 'authentication facility') - just define an appropriate authentication scheme and django-rest-framework does all for you: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: same goes for django itself. Django has the same functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`authenticate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate). There is no need of hashing the password by yourself, Django already do that. You just have to pass the username and password to authenticate function and it will return you the corresponding User object.

```
def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
```

Comment: I am creating an api post request with email and password as parameters if the user exist in the system i return some data. the user have to specify his username and password, i am creating this api to allow all my users to access some data only if they have a account at my website.

Comment: @gabyawad If you have username field than it's better to use it instead of email

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `check_password`. Every user in django has this method. It will automatically hash it and compare it with the one saved before:

```
user.check_password(raw_password)
```

Hope it helps!